# Content of canvas changes resolution when zooming in or out, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

recently I've tried to fix this problem I had for the past week, basically I wanted to block the zoom of my canvas by using VMIN, VMAX, VH, VW so the user couldn't zoom in or out and make the canvas and it's content larger or smaller, I actually achieved that but for some reason the content gets blurry when I zoom in and gets more detailed when I zoom out making everything slower.
I've tried to change the method of rendering of the canvas in the css but nothing, I also see a lot of people using the window.devicePixelRatio but either I used it wrong or that messes up the function that blocks the zoom of the canvas.

**------- EXAMPLE -------**

*Before* zooming in (Zoom = 100%)

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlmGC.jpg)

*After* zooming in (Zoom = 500%)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHOdK.jpg)

**-------- CODE --------**

***Here is the code snippet of where I use the gameCanvas:***

```css
#gameCanvas{
    
    position: absolute;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
    z-index: -5;
}
```

***And here is my Main.js script:***

```js
import Utils from "./other/Utils.js"
import {Game} from "./Game.js";

//=== GLOBAL VARIABLES ===============================================================================

console.log("\n"+Utils.getTime(":")+"\n\n");

const container = document.getElementById("canvasSpace");
const canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

const CANVAS_WIDTH = 100;
const CANVAS_HEIGHT = 100;

var VH = 1;
var VW = 1;
var VMIN = 1;
var VMAX = 1;

let secondsPassed = 0;
let oldTimeStamp = 0;
let timePassed = 0;

let debugPause = false;

var global = {
    
    getVH: function(perc){
        return VH*perc;
    },

    getVW: function(perc){
        return VW*perc;
    },

    getVMIN: function(perc){
        return VMIN*perc;
    },

    getVMAX: function(perc){
        return VMAX*perc;
    },
    
    getCanvasWidth: function(){
        return Utils.clamp(100, (getWindowWidth()/100)*CANVAS_WIDTH, 820);
    },
    
    getCanvasHeight: function(){
        return Utils.clamp(100, (getWindowHeight()/100)*CANVAS_HEIGHT, 1180);
    },

    getContainer: function(){
        return container;
    },

    doc: document,

    win: window,

    ctx: context,

    readJSONFile: function(filePath){
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', filePath, false);
        request.send();

        if (request.status === 200) 
        {
            return JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        } 
        else 
        {
            throw new Error(`Failed to load JSON file from ${filePath}`);
        }
    },

    nextScene: function(){
        game.nextScene();
    },

    getEaseTimeVar: function(){ //^ Used for easing [Matteo]
        var timeStamp = performance.now();
        secondsPassed = (timeStamp - oldTimeStamp) / 1000;
        oldTimeStamp = timeStamp;

        timePassed += secondsPassed;

        return timeStamp;
    },
    
};

responsivityUpdate();


//=== MAIN SETUP ===============================================================================

var game = new Game(global);

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.code === 'Space') {
        debugPause = debugPause == true ? false : true;
    }
});

update();

//=== MAIN LOOP ===============================================================================

function update()
{
    
    if(!debugPause)
    {   
        responsivityUpdate();  

        //!_____
        game.update();
        
        //|_____
        draw();
        
    }
        
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function draw() //^ draw() has the purpose to ONLY draw (and also call requestAnimationFrame() to mantain the loop) on the canvas
{
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.fillStyle = "#F5E7C3";
    context.fillRect(0,0,global.getCanvasWidth(),global.getCanvasHeight());

    game.draw();

}


//=== FUNCTIONS ===============================================================================

function responsivityUpdate() //^ Ensures the canvas size and the respective viewports are reactive to the window size [Xavier]
{
    
    /* let ratio = window.devicePixelRatio;
    canvas.style.width = (global.getCanvasWidth()*ratio) + "px"; 
    canvas.style.height = (global.getCanvasHeight()*ratio) + "px";   */

    //? Align canvas size to our desired dimensions
    canvas.width = global.getCanvasWidth();
    canvas.height = global.getCanvasHeight();

    //? Calculating again the viewports values
    VW = (global.getCanvasWidth())/100;
    VH = (global.getCanvasHeight())/100;

    if(VH>VW)
    {
        VMAX = VH;
        VMIN = VW;
    }
    else{
        VMAX = VW;
        VMIN = VH;
    }

    //? Aligning the canvas to the center
    canvas.style.top = parseFloat(getCanvasOffsetX()) + "px"; 
    canvas.style.left = parseFloat(getCanvasOffsetY()) + "px"; 


    container.style.width = parseFloat(global.getCanvasWidth()) + "px";
    container.style.height = parseFloat(global.getCanvasHeight()) + "px";
    container.style.top = parseFloat(getCanvasOffsetX()) + "px";
    container.style.left = parseFloat(getCanvasOffsetY()) + "px";

}

function getCanvasOffsetX() //^ Returns the width of the space between the window top left corner and the canvas top left corner
{
    return ((getWindowHeight()/100)*((100-CANVAS_HEIGHT)/2).toFixed(2));
}

function getCanvasOffsetY() //^ Returns the height of the space between the window top left corner and the canvas top left corner
{
    return ((getWindowWidth()/100)*((100-CANVAS_WIDTH)/2).toFixed(2));
}

function getWindowWidth() //^ Returns the window width removing any external element width (scrollbars,topbar,...) [Xavier]
{
    /*
    ? There are multiple possible ways to get it depending on the browser, that's why I added more options
    */
    return (window.innerWidth || window.visualViewport.width || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth);
}

function getWindowHeight() //^ Returns the window height removing any external element height (scrollbars,topbar,...) [Xavier]
{
    /*
    ? Returns the window height removing any external element height (scrollbars,topbar,...) 
    */
    return (window.innerHeight || window.visualViewport.height || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight);
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Re code TLDR. Note that setting [HTMLCanvasElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement).width or height sets the canvas resolution (number of pixels in the canvas image). Setting the canvas `style.width` or `style.height` sets the canvas display size. Your blurry image shows a low resolution image  (canvas) rendered many times larger (~5) to the page (or another canvas). The blur is due to the linear interpolation between pixels that the compositor (renderer) uses when upscaling an image.

Comment: You could disable zooming on the whole page (on mobile) with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">`